# In angular 4: ReferenceError: d3 is not defined while on importing in module

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to import this in my app.module in angular 4. Instead of inserting it on my index file.

```
In app.module.ts -> 

import d3 from "d3";
console.log(d3) // shows that D3 is successfully imported

import nvd3 from "nvd3";
```

Page throwing following Error:

> ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Also, I have added those dependencies in package.json

Comment: @AmruthLS, no it is not a duplicate

Comment: How come its a duplicate? @AmruthLS ? Do explain.

Comment: try `import * as d3 from d3`

Comment: @HuguesStefanskiI  I have tried it. It is not working. Still getting same error.

Comment: I suggest you use ngx-charts better than nvd3

Answer (score 0):

just use in your module,

```
import 'd3';
import 'nvd3';
```

and just declare d3 in your component on the top

```
declare var d3: any;
```

Comment: Declare d3 in your component on the top: - declare var d3: any;